# How to set length for enum type in migration Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a migration for MySQL:

```
 class MakeEventsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->enum('type', ['sync', 'start_event', 'end_end', 'start_meeting_session', 'last_track_time'])->;
                $table->timestamp('created_at');
            });
        }
}
```

As a result, I have an error:

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row
>   1 (SQL: insert into `events` (`item_id`, `item_type`, `type`,
>   `created_at`) values (45, meeting, last_track_time, 2018-02-14
>   06:52:10))

This is because field **type** too small, and I am finding out a solution, how to increase the length of the field?

Comment: Is that your actual code used? You have a "->" at the end of the enum definition. You shouldn't have to set the length of an enum field.

Comment: Did the migration run successfully? As far as I know you can’t name a field `type` in MySQL. What’s the output of `DESCRIBE events`? What’s the value inserted? An empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the same and try this way... hope it will work.

```
$table->enum('event_info', ['sync', 'start_event', 'end_end', 'start_meeting_session', 'last_track_time']);
```